# php validation - in or outside the function?

Tags: php, security, validation

What is the proper way of validating data? I mean say you have an insert function:

```
function newUser($name, $lastname, $age) {

   // some validation process

   $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO user VALUES (?,?,?)", 
                       array($name, $lastname, $age)); // this is another class
                                                       // that runs execute in itself

}
```

So basically, the question is whether the `//some validation procecss` part should take place in newUser function or should it be done outside the function? I am asking this because I am writing a request class which I will store basic validation rules in that class and automatically filter my `get` and `post` values. So if I do that, and if I also validate inside newUser (similarly on other functions like this) it means that I will validate the same input twice or maybe thrice.

So in short, is there anything wrong if I assume that variables that are passed to function newUser are already validated? In this case, I am also assuming that newUser is only called from my application (I am not sure whether a third party can also run the function without my permission, this is actually why I asked the question) and therefore the variables are already validated before having called the newUser function.

P.S: Sorry if the question is asked in a complicated way, just comment if you don't understand what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, i would make a validation class, this contains kinds of validation (for email, string, numbers, string and numbers).

Depending on what you want the vars in your function to be, validate them like that and put them in the database.

A third party shouldn't be able to run your function if you make sure you script safely.

Example how not to script:

```
include( $_GET['file'] );
```

Basically, I could put a own file to include in your system using the ?file parameter in your URL. Also with queries is this possible:

```
mysql_query( "INSERT INTO table (row) VALUES (". $_GET['value'] .")" );
```

You should always check parameters that can be accessed from outside of your scripts, so in your case making a new user, you would have to validate it in your new user function before you put it in your database.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm planning. But what do you mean by "script safely". Can you show me an example of unsafe script?

Comment: Well there is a thing called XXS, cross side scripting. It allows third party people to put their own script into your script. I will put an example in my post.

Comment: ah well, ok. I thought something that I didn't know :) While validating I'm, of course, also -trying- to prevent any xss or sql injection attack :)

Comment: It doesn't really matter where you validate, as long you do it. Best is using a pattern like Aurelio said. Although somewhere you still going to validate and call your new user function!

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you are working. For example, if you were using the MVC pattern, the test should be done in the Controller (so not in the function you are using).
In your case you have to choose if you have to validate the data using a validation function (or maybe a method of a class) and then use the one you wrote to insert the data or to let this function to ensure them. I would suggest you the first solution so the "insert" function will achieve just one task.

Just to improve my answer, I suggest you to ensure the data at least for the SQL Injection and for the XSS (Cross Site Scripting).

Comment: So following the first suggestion, I would not have to check inside `newUser`, say, if the name is empty or not right?

Comment: @Shaokan No. Because if you're writing software following the good tips of software engineering, every method/function should achieve just one task. In this case, one method/function to ensure the data, another one to add the data.